# Is there a way to extract code that constructs a data frame from the data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to extract code that constructs a data frame, from the loaded data frame.

Consider the following process.

```
# Code to construct a df:

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

# Obtain the df output:

df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```

I am looking for an automatized reverse process. Suppose, I start with the df, which I load from a csv file (example below, same df as above).

```
df = 
pd.read_csv('/path_to_data/df.csv', sep='\t')
df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```

At this point, is there a way to extract the code (listed below), that would construct the df, assuming that I did not have the code to begin with.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
    index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

This is not always useful, but I am curious if this can be done, for certain portability purposes. For instance, this would allow sharing one jupyter notebook document, without referencing anything external. And allow for a fully self-sustained replicability of data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information using `df.to_dict('list')` and `df.index` respectively:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8

In [10]: df.to_dict('list')
Out[10]:
{'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
 'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
 'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]}

In [11]: df.index
Out[11]: Index(['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'], dtype='object')

In [12]: new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict('list'), index=df.index)

In [13]: new_df
Out[13]:
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```